# loggerプロパティと、logMessageメソッドの実装について

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure

このサイトに、
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Graph-SDK-iOS

```
[self.resolver.logger logMessage:@"Connected." withLevel:LOG_LEVEL_INFO];
```

というコードのloggerプロパティと、logMessageメソッドが書かれているのですが、これらはどこで実装されているのでしょうか？

ADALDependencyResolver Class Referenceを見ても、載っていません。

http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Office365/0.8.2/Classes/ADALDependencyResolver.html

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logMessageメソッドそのものは、MSOrcLogLevel.hで宣言されているMSOrcLoggerプロトコルで宣言されています。実際に実装されているのは、MSOrcLoggerImpl.h/MSOrcLoggerImpl.mのMSOrcLoggerImplになります。

宣言／定義された位置がわからない場合の調べ方ですが、とりあえず、シンボルを右クリックして『Jump to Definition』をやってみるのが手っ取り早いかと思いますよ。

[image: Jump to Definition]